# JSON output in smarty template

Tags: php, json, smarty

I have a php file which outputs a json object . I wanted to display a set of records of those outputs to display in a smarty template . But when I echo the json object , is is showing like

```
[{"fname":"kashmiri","lname":"medhi"},{"fname":"Kangkan","lname":"Hazarika"},{"fname":"ikram","lname":"hussain"}]
```

in outside the template . I am using jQuery getJSON() function .
The PHP file :

```
foreach($res as $a=>$v)
            {
                $arr['fname'] = $v->UM_first_name;
                $arr['lname'] = $v->UM_last_name;
                $data[] = $arr;
            }
            $json_obj = json_encode($data);
            echo $json_obj;
```

The js file :

```
$('document').ready(function()
{
    $.getJSON('http://localhost/basic_framework/index.php ?menu=search_22',callBack);

});
function callBack(data)
{
    $.each(data,function(i,fi)
    {   
        var info ='';       
        info+=dte.lc;
        info+='<div id="ids">'+fi.fname[0]+'</div>';
        info+='<div id="nws">'+fi.lname[0]+'</div>';

        $(info).appendTo("#friend_info");
    });
}
```

Where I am doing the wrong ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your question is. What goes wrong where?

Comment: Same as Pekka. And where does  the "dte.lc" comes from? Why do you try to append fi.fname[0] instead of fi.fname in your JS loop?

Comment: Sorry .I info+=dte.lc was from my testing file . plz skip the line . And fi.lname[0] because its an array of names of different users . ideally it should be fi.lname[i].

Comment: Your outputed JSON doesn't seem to have arrays in fname and lname, but rather plain strings.
$.each() already iterates through your array, so your fi object is just an object having one fname property and one lname property.

Comment: OK thanks PJP...I modified it to info+='<div id="ids">'+fi.fname+'</div>';bt still nt showing anything within the template

Comment: Can you trace what is returned by your server with Firebug, for instance?
That would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you right, you should use return instead of your echo. 
Because your echo will be in another thread and it won't make the callback() function work.

Comment: I think the PHP script is the one he calls with his $.getJSON call. So echo is OK.

Comment: Maybe you should use jQuery.parseJSON(data) in your callback before each() function?

Comment: As he uses $.getJSON(), there is no need to parse the data. jQuery already do this.